# background image linear gradient not working on navbar

Tags: html, css

I checked out a few other similar posts bit it didn't help. I'm unable to use background-image: linear-gradient() in css. Also, the font-family in css is not being applied.

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#nav-bar
{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
.navbar
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a517ba, #a5f1782);
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-nav li a
{
    color: #000 !important;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">

<head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"  ></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section id = "nav-bar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </section>

    <p>"Hello World!"</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The correct value for `lang=` attribute is `en`, not `eng`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use font families you have to use quotation marks (""), for the problem about the navbar, have you tried using the default navbar of the Boostrap site?

Answer (score 1):

You've misspelled a HEX code.
Change the line with the background image to

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a517ba, #a5f1782);
```

I'm not sure why your font isn't being applied, as it's a generic font family, but I also spotted a few other errors:

- You've got a syntax error on line 5
- You should set lang attribute to en, not eng

Answer (score 1):

You have typo in color code.

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a517ba, #a5f1782);
                                                     │       │
                                              HERE ──┴───────┘
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#nav-bar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.navbar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a517ba, #a5f178);
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
  color: #000 !important;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">

<head>
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" </script>
    < script src = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" >
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="nav-bar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </section>

  <p>"Hello World!"</p>
</body>

</html>
```